# Button in Sitecore MVC

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

How we can create a simple asp button and call onclick event of this button in Sitecore MVC.

I have tried http://www.experimentsincode.com/?p=425 blog for this but it's not working for me.

Does any one have any idea how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You should really read up on MVC.NET in general before attempting to do anything with Sitecore MVC.

There is no such thing as a server-side click event on a button, that is something .NET WebForms implemented for you but in MVC.NET it does not exist.

If you need a server-side action based on a client-side click, you need Javascript to handle the click event, call the server-side action using an AJAX call and then act on the result of that action.
Or you could implement the button as a link that points to an action on a controller.

Comment: thank you for your inputs that are really helpful. Could you please tell me some information about insert update delete operations  in site core MVC